# React Js Call Function from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use **getIncome()** and **getExpense()** from *IncomeExpense.js* File in the *Balance.J*s file. I have Context API in placement as well but I think I cannot use it to use the child function of another component.

IncomeExpense.js

```
function IncomeExpense() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    let {transactions} = useContext(TransactionContext);

    function FormRow() {

        function getIncome() {
            let income = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++)
            {
                if (transactions[i].amount > 0)
                {
                    income += transactions[i].amount;
                }

            }
            return income;
        };

        const getExpense = () => {
            let expense = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++)
            {
                if (transactions[i].amount < 0)
                {
                    expense -= transactions[i].amount;
                }
            }
            return expense;
        };
        // console.log(getExpense())

        return (
                            <Typography className={classes.weight} align="center" variant="h5" component="h2">
                                INCOME
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography className={classes.colorGreen + ' ' + classes.weight} align="center" variant="body2" component="p">

                                +${getIncome()}
                            </Typography>

                     <Typography className={classes.weight} align="center" variant="h5" component="h2">
                         EXPENSE
                      </Typography>
                     <Typography className={classes.colorRed + ' ' + classes.weight} align="center" variant="body2" component="p">

                         -${getExpense()}
                     </Typography>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
                    <FormRow />
        </div>
    );
}

export default IncomeExpense;
```

Balance.js

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import IncomeExpense from "../IncomeExpense/IncomeExpense";

const Balance = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>YOUR BALANCE <br/> ${ getIncome() } </h2>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Balance;
```

please let me know if you need more code to inspect the problem. Thanks

Comment: Is there any reasons you can't make Balance a child component of IncomeExpense?

Comment: If you need these functions used in both components, maybe you should define these functions in the two components' first common ancestor.

Comment: Yes I can make Balance a child component of IncomeExpense but I also want to know if in future I face similar problem then how can I use one component in another @Jacob

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi yeah, the Context could be used for this but it seems like overkill for two functions to be passed to one component.

I would say either making it a child/parent or Lift State/Functions to the common parent.

Comment: Context is one way for sure but keep in mind that makes them co-dependent, I would agree with Ghassen that lifting the behavior to the first common parent, pass the state from Income would update the parents internal state and therefore update Balance's state

Comment: Either way, they'll need to be passed to these components as props. Although another idea is to extract these function into their own class (something like `TransactionManager`), this class would be shared across different React components that need it,

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Oh like a Custom Hook?

Comment: Doesn't need to be a hook, for example, a class that defines and exposes these functions, and in your React component you do `import TM from './TransactionManager.js';`, then within the component itself, you can do `TM.getIncome(transactions)`.

Comment: I should mention that if going with that approach, the functions need to be [pure](https://www.nicoespeon.com/en/2015/01/pure-functions-javascript/#:~:text=A%20pure%20function%20doesn't,a%20pillar%20of%20functional%20programming), meaning they do not make assumptions about the component's state nor do they cause any side effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems both functions are fairly simple, each is a function of only one variable: `transactions`.  While some commenters are suggesting to put these in the next common ancestors of `IncomeExpense` and `Balance`, another option is to disassociate them completely from your components.  Keep them as constants in some `actions` file, then import them and use them with `transactions` as an argument (similar to Ghassen Louhaichi's comment).  This is also good practice if you ever want to incorporate redux.

```js
// actions.js

export const getIncome = transactions => {

  let income = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++) {
    if (transactions[i].amount > 0) {
      income += transactions[i].amount;
    }
  }
  return income;

};

export const getExpense = transactions => {

  let expense = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++) {
    if (transactions[i].amount < 0) {
      expense -= transactions[i].amount;
    }
  }
  return expense;

};
```

I also suggest that you make `FormRow` its own component.  Its a little strange to have it defined entire within the `IncomeExpense` component.  Now you can use it elsewhere.

```js
// FormRow.js

import { getIncome, getExpense } from './actions.js'

const classes = useStyles()
let {transactions} = useContext(TransactionContext);


const FormRow = () = {

  return (
      <Typography ... >
        INCOME
      </Typography>
      <Typography ... >
        +${getIncome(transactions)}
      </Typography>

      <Typography ... >
        EXPENSE
      </Typography>
      <Typography ... >
        -${getExpense(transactions)}
      </Typography>
    )

}
```

If all `IncomeExpense` does is return `FormRow`, maybe they don't need to be separate components?

```js
// IncomeExpense.js
// Does this need to be a separate component than FormRow?

import FormRow from './FormRow'

const classes = useStyles()

function IncomeExpense() {

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <FormRow />
    </div>
  )
}

export default IncomeExpense;
```

```js
// Balance.js

import React, {useContext, useContext} from "react";
import IncomeExpense from "../IncomeExpense/IncomeExpense";
import { getIncome, getExpense } from './actions.js'

let {transactions} = useContext(TransactionContext);

const Balance = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>YOUR BALANCE <br/> ${ getIncome(transactions) } </h2>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Balance;
```

Comment: Thank You for taking time.
if we make actions.js then there will be an error for the transaction array. and If i usecontext() there then I have to make a function compatible with the Hooks and it will become the same thing as in IncomeExoense.js

Comment: Yes it is only returning FormRow for now but in case if I work on other project and face similar thing maybe I couldn’t just ignore it that is why I am trying to solve this problem

Comment: I realized I didnt add the `const { transactions } = useContext(TransactionContext)` to `FormRow`.  I edited it.  So now, you pull `transactions` out of your context, and then use it as the argument to `getIncome` and  `getExpense`.

Comment: I'm glad that helped you. Its customary to mark an answer that helped you as the answer, and/or upvote it.  Everyone loves meaningless internet points.

Comment: Sure, I marked it as the answer. They recorded the vote but not showing in public. Because my reputation is < 15. But I will be well reputed one day and this Upvote will be public for sure.

Comment: that's the spirit